# Azure application back up configuration error:Failed to save Backup Configuration

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to configure a back up for an application with schedule backup set to false. We do manual backups and I get this error

"Failed to save Backup Configuration.  Error Details: Requested backup frequency exceeds maximum allowed for the plan."

As far as I can see, since schedule backup is set to false there is no request back up frequency.

What am I missing here.

Backup storage set to a container and blob
backup schedule is off
Include database backup is off

Application is using standard tier and container and application all are under same Azure subscription.

Comment: this might help https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/aef97b0e-95fb-4977-9d1d-2d3a5345e7fe/canamp39t-update-my-web-application-backup-settings?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview

Comment: Thanks @ManishTiwari, I checked that link also, it goes into schedules and I am not scheduling any of that. All is under one subscription and under standard tier also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Backup and Restore feature requires the App Service plan to be in the **Standard** tier or **Premium** tier. For the error message, you could upgrade the app service price tier to a higher tier. For example, you can scale up to **P1** tier.

Please note that there are [app service limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits#app-service-limits), The following App Service limits include limits for Web Apps, Mobile Apps, and API Apps.

For **standard** tier,

> Scheduled backups every 2 hours, a maximum of 12 backups per day
>   (manual + scheduled)

[image]

For more information, you could see that [requirements and restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-backup#requirements-and-restrictions) when you backup your app in Azure.

---

**Edit**

As confirmed by Azure PG,

> There is no restriction on number of apps under one subscription that
>   can be backed up. If the customer has 4 apps in Standard SKU, each can
>   be backed up for 12 times / day.
>
> Also, this is a known Bug 5913246: Enabling Manual Backup submits
>   settings for Hourly Backup
>
> Workaround for this is to Create a Daily Schedule first, save this,
>   then remove the schedule afterward.

So, to fix this, you can manually create a backup with the scheduled backup set to `on`, after backup succeeded, you can go back to set the scheduled backup `off`.

Comment: Thanks @Nancy, yes I had looked into that document and confirmed that app services are in standard tier. Azure storage and containers are in the same subscription as well. All requirements are met. Its really strange because we have about 4 apps already getting backed up. I am wondering if there is a restriction that only a certain number of apps under one subscription can be backed up?

Comment: I am facing the same error when I use standard tier, but use P1, the error disappears, you could try it again?

Comment: That is strange, is that a new bug or something, because I had configured about 5 applications several months back that use standard tier and they worked fine. Back up for those already configured applications in standard tier worked just fine yesterday too. Just configuring new backups for applications that are in standard tier is causing an issue. We really don't want to  push them to Premium tier. I wonder if there is a way for me to change them to premium, configure back up and then turn them back to standard?

Comment: There is an app service limit `Scheduled backups every 2 hours, a maximum of 12 backups per day (manual + scheduled)`. Please verify it on your side.

Comment: We have no scheduled backups and no manual backups got done today and still having the issue. Also confirmed since this is production environment and all apps are on same service plan of standard tier, we don't want to move them to P1. Need this to work on standard tier.

Comment: Nancy, thank you so much. Sorry for the late response. I tried it this morning and the work around worked perfectly. We have backups for the remaining applications now.